# Java JMenu actionPerformed doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener, jmenu

So, I've implemented anonymous action listener to JMenu component, so I'm wonder is it possible for JMenu to do some action with out JMenuItems in it, just JMenu, for example... Exit?

```
@Override
    public void menuBarItemExit(JMenuBar menubar) {
        exitMenuItem = new JMenu("Exit");
        exitMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        menubar.add(exitMenuItem);
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Use a `MenuListener` instead of an `ActionListener`:

```
exitMenuItem.addMenuListener(new MenuListener() {
    @Override
    public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent e) {
    }
});
```

From Oracle: [JMenu ignores ActionEvent](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4108937)